# Error on joining DataFrame on PySpark 2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having trouble using Spark 2.3.1 and PySpark.

Firstable I was trying to do all lot of different operations like join and columns select and at the end collect it or save it into a csv file but spark trowed me a Py4JJavaError.

My First error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o482.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
```

EDIT full error stack http://textuploader.com/d21se

I tried to increase the broadcastTimeout according to https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150263/orgapachesparksparkexception-exception-thrown-in-a.html
but it still not working.

So I tried a smaller operation like a joint. I have two DataFrame that are about 50MB each. I tried a join like :

```
l.join(r, l["ir"] == r["ir"], how="outer").show()
```

When l and r are my DataFrame and ir is the key.

I still get an error like

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3584.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I am not really sure what to do and where the problem comes from. If anyone could help !

**EDIT**: After more investigation it seems to a be problem of the number of columns in total when I do the join. I tried to do this:

```
l = l.selectExpr(*list(np.unique(l.columns[:-7] + ["ir"])))
l.join(r, l["ir"] == r["ir"], how="outer").show()`
```

and

```
l = l.selectExpr(*list(np.unique(l.columns[-7:] + ["ir"])))
l.join(r, l["ir"] == r["ir"], how="outer").show()
```

Both worked, for people that are not familiar to python, I just selected a subsample in the first expression from column 0 to -7 (-7 is 7 before end) + the key and in second expr from column -7 to end

Both working means that every columns can go in the join and it is not a pb with the data but with the number of column. I think it could be a spark configuration pb but not sure.

Comment: provide your complete error log

Comment: https://textuploader.com/d21se

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Can you please cross check your data. I didn’t find any error in the log related to memory

Comment: The merge works on python Pandas DataFrame. Not really sure what to check

When I show both dataframe on spark the show work. The only operation is the join

Comment: Could you please provide your sample data. I want to recreate the issue. There is some issue with your data.

Comment: Actually I can't share those data, I tried to do the join with only 1 column and it worked

Comment: After a long check I found out that reducing the number of column for a df to join solve the problem. The problem is that I need all columns. Do you have solution ?

Comment: I would say that reducing the columns is not the solution. Try one column at a time and see which column gives you error

Comment: I tried that, but it is not a question of one column, it is a question of the number of columns. I tried to do this :
`l = l.selectExpr(*list(np.unique(l.columns[:-7] + ["ir"]))); l.join(r, l["ir"] == r["ir"], how="outer").show()`
and
`l = l.selectExpr(*list(np.unique(l.columns[-7:] + ["key"])));l.join(r, l["ir"] == r["ir"], how="outer").show()`
Both worked

Comment: Send the schema of the two dataframes

Comment: first DF:
https://textuploader.com/d2135

Second DF:
https://textuploader.com/d213a

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by downgrading to Java 1.8 .... My Java Version was 1.10